# On linux in C how to generate file of size X?

Tags: c, linux, file

So I want to make a file named genData.c that when executed for example: ./genData filename.txt       will write 1 character to that file 1000 times.

In essence creating a 1kb file. 
I would like to be able to modify the for loop, say 100000 times, to generate a 1MB file and so on.

Here is what I have tried and it compiles but when executed causes a segmentation fault.

Any suggestions? Sorry C is a language I've never dabbled in.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv) {
    char ch = 'A';
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "wb");
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        fwrite(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think logically about it. You can use `fwrite` to write a buffer of a size of your choosing instead of just one character. **See the documentation.** So you could declare a buffer of, say, `1,024` bytes (1K) and fill it with what data you wish. Then tell `fwrite` you want to write it `1,024` times. That's 1MB.

Comment: Add a check to make sure that `fopen` was successful. `if ( fp != NULL ) { ... }`.

Answer (score 5):

If you compile with warnings, you get a hint as to the exact problem:

```
test.c:3:5: warning: second argument of ‘main’ should be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]
 int main (int argc, char *argv) {
     ^
```

All your troubles start downstream of this error. Fix this argument, and your code will work.

In the future, get into the habit of compiling with warnings turned on:

```
$ gcc -Wall foo.c
...
```

This will help catch typos and other oddities that will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged it Linux, this is how you can do it with the system-level functions (this should be a correct, most efficient way to do it):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

ssize_t             /* Write "n" bytes to a descriptor  */
writen(int fd, const void *ptr, size_t n);

int 
main (int argc, char** argv) {
  char buf[1000];
  memset(buf, 'A', sizeof(buf));
  int fd;
  if((fd = open(argv[1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666))<0){
    perror(argv[1]);
    exit(EX_NOPERM);
  }
  ssize_t left = writen(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
  if(left) 
    perror("write error\n"); 
  return !!left;
}

ssize_t             /* Write "n" bytes to a descriptor  */
writen(int fd, const void *ptr, size_t n) {
  size_t        nleft;
  ssize_t       nwritten;

  nleft = n;
  while (nleft > 0) {
    if ((nwritten = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) < 0) {
      if (nleft == n)
        return(-1); /* error, return -1 */
      else
        break;      /* error, return amount written so far */
    } else if (nwritten == 0) {
      break;
    }
    nleft -= nwritten;
    ptr   += nwritten;
  }
  return(n - nleft);      /* return >= 0 */
}
```

Comment: If you only ever need to create a regular file than a single `write` instead of `writen` should do it or else it's an error. `writen` is only needed to ensure correct behavior for special output files like sockets and pipes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE_OF_FILE  1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     FILE *fdest;
     char ch = '\n';

     if(argc != 2)
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

     fdest = fopen(argv[1], "wb");
     if (fdest == NULL)
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

     fseek(fdest, SIZE_OF_FILE - 1, SEEK_CUR);
     fwrite(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, fdest);

     fclose(fdest);


     return 0;
}
```

> In essence creating a 1kb file

if the only purpose is creating a file with sizeof x, it is more simple i belive.

Comment: This helped a lot.  I was wondering would you be able to show me how to implement my own cp command in c code? I want to create a buffer variable, read in X bytes from file1, and write X bytes to file2. And keep doing this until EOF of file1 is reached.  I am doing this to test how different buffer sizes effect performance but my C skills are terrible.